# Onsubmit con JavaScript y PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Estoy aprendiendo un poco con JavaScript y PHP.

El caso, es que tengo un formulario (`form`). Una vez rellenado tiene dos procesos.

Uno es PHP, que recoge los `$POST` del html con `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` y los procesa para exportarlo a texto a una ruta fija local automáticamente (sin descarga).

**Una vez acaba, lanza un header a la página de resultados.**

Y por otro lado, tengo un `onsubmit` en el `form`, que dispara un JavaScript, que recoge todo el documento y genera un PDF mediante JSPDF. Este mismo JavaScript, se sirve de JQuery - AJAX para mandar la información a otro PHP de procesamiento y que me lo almacene de manera local (automáticamente sin `headers`, lo guarda en una ruta concreta).

La cuestión concreta es, al hacerlo de este modo, en dos vías, muchas veces uno acaba antes que el otro y el procesamiento de alguna de las dos no termina y me genera un archivo corrupto o no llega a generarlo (el PDF corrupto es lo habitual).

La pregunta es, como podría disparar para que primero me hiciera la parte con java y posteriormente el `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` del PHP?

O alguna manera para unificar el proceso y que no vayan 'cada uno por su lado'.

Igual hay algo que no conozco, como un evento o similar...

Parcialmente he solventado el problema en la primera parte, haciendo un `sleep` antes de enviar el `header` hacia la pagina de resultados (espera x segundos), así acaba de procesar la segunda parte y sin problema, pero no lo veo óptimo.

Se agradece cualquier ayuda. Gracias.

Comment: Puedes mostrar el código que tienes? Porque no entiendo como que uno acaba antes que otro, ya que si realizas llamadas Ajax puedes esperar a que termine uno y luego lanzar la otra acción.

Comment: uno va con el onclick al js y otro en el php de la propia pagina, con un if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ recogiendo las variables post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que necesitas es que ejecute el Javascript y después el PHP, cambia el submit por un button para que no se envié el formulario al pulsarlo. En este button llamas a la función que necesites de Javascript para que te cree el fichero

`<input type='button' onclick='function()'>`

Al final de la función de javascript mandas el formulario al PHP

`$('#id_form').submit()`

Con esto hasta que no termine de ejecutarse todo el Javascript no empezara el PHP.

Comment: También es una idea muy buena. Se ma había pasado por la cabeza la verdad.

Parece las más sencilla.

Answer (score 0):

Uitlizar sleep no es una solución acertada. No se me ocurre ninguna forma de trabajar dos caminos diferentes desde dos tecnologías distintas (PHP/Javascript) por lo que lo que haría sería lo siguiente:

1. Solo ejecutaría el onsubmit y crearía un único flujo de trabajo en Javascript.
2. Crearía el fichero PDF
3. Una vez creado el fichero, enviamos mediante AJAX la información del formulario serializada al fichero PHP (puedes usar un callback de la anterior función)

De esta forma disponemos de un único flujo de trabajo y cada acción se ejecuta de forma lineal.

Comment: Interesante, lo que comentas. O sea ir solo por javascript, generar el pdf como hasta ahora, y que además el propio javascript me recoja las variables y las envíe para procesar el CSV. ¿Sería algo así verdad?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Eso es, si usas jquery con serialize ya tienes todas las variables del formulario en el flujo https://api.jquery.com/serialize/